# Picking a resource file at build time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac, resx

I'm creating a multi facade website, that is basically the same website, same function but has a different URL and theme, name, logo etc. is different based on renting the service out.

So I was wondering, to make publishing all different versions, how I would handle the differences. I thought `.resx` or `resource files` would maybe help. So I could store names, different about us text, links, logos and such in `.resx` files. I guess I would have one file for each facade and somehow pick between them at build time, based on configuration perhaps.

I'm already doing DI with `autofac` for testing and in case some facade might in the future have to do things a little differently.

The problem with the this solution is that each file has it's own name and it's all static methods. I can't create a interface for static methods. Can I bind a resource file under generic name somehow in application_start method perhaps.

Any suggestions or solutions

Comment: Multitenant feature might help you here: http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MultitenantIntegration

Comment: @AlexandrNikitin I will take a look but my problem is different from Multi Tenancy because the sites are hosted separately. But if something works with multi tenancy it might work with multi build configuration style as well.